# SQLite and concurrency

Tags: sqlite

I need to integrate a database in one of our products and I wonder which one would be more suited to our needs (easy automatic deployment, no administration, good performance), and sqlite seems to be a good solution. The problem is that the database could potentially face high concurrency issues: it is accessed through PHP (Apache) each time a client connects to the server the database is running on. One client connects (and execute an INSERT query) approximatively every 10 seconds to the server, and it could possibly have more than 100 clients running.

When executing an INSERT query, sqlite locks the entire database at a certain time for a certain duration. Is there a way to compute that duration? If this is not possible, do you think sqlite (v3.3.7) is still adapted with the above conditions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think that SQLite would be a good solution for those requirements. SQLite is designed for local and lightweight use only, not to serve hundreds of requests.

I would recommend some other solution, for example `MySQL` or `PostgreSQL`, both can be scripted quite well. So, if I were you, I would put my efforts into the setup scriptings.

To avoid the flame war between SQLite believers and haters, let me draw draw your attention to the often referred [SQLite When-To-Use](http://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html) document (I believe it is considered as a credible source). Here they state the following:

> **Situations Where A Client/Server RDBMS May Work Better**
>
> *High Concurrency*
>
> SQLite supports an unlimited number of simultaneous readers, but it will only allow one writer at any instant in time. For many situations, this is not a problem. Writer queue up. Each application does its database work quickly and moves on, and no lock lasts for more than a few dozen milliseconds. But there are some applications that require more concurrency, and those applications may need to seek a different solution.

I think that in the referred question involves many writes and if the OP would go for SQLite, it would result a non-scalable solution.

Answer (score 81):

I try to avoid emotive replies and hyperbole but I am truly **astonished** at the lack of knowledge about sqlite displayed on this page. Different database implementations serve different needs and from the operational specs you provide, sqlite3 seems ideal for your needs. To elaborate:

sqlite3 is fully ACID compliant, meaning it ensures atomic commits, which is something neither MySQL (good as it may be) nor Oracle can brag about. See more [here](http://adamfowlerml.wordpress.com/2013/01/25/true-acid-compliance/)

Also, sqlite3 has a deceptively simple mechanism for ensuring maximum concurrency (which is also thread-safe) as described in their [File locking and Concurrency document](http://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html).

By their (sqlite3 developers') own estimation, sqlite3 is capable of up to 50,000 INSERTs per second - a theoretical maximum which is limited by disk rotation speed. ACID compliance requires sqlite3 to confirm that a database commit has been written to disk, so an INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE transaction requires two full disk rotations, thereby effectively reducing the number of transactions to 60/s on a 7200rpm diskdrive. This is outlined in the sqlite FAQ linked in another answer and the fact gives some idea of the engine's data throughput capability in production. But what about concurrent reading and writing?

The File locking and Concurrency document linked earlier, explains how sqlite3 avoids "writer startvation" - a condition whereby heavy database read access prevents a process/thread seeking to write to the database from acquiring a lock. The escalation of locking state from SHARED to PENDING to EXCLUSIVE happens as sqlite3 encounters an INSERT (or UPDATE or DELETE) statement and then again upon COMMIT, meaning that the full database lock is delayed to the last moment before an actual write is performed. The outcome of sqlite's clever mechanism for handling file locking means that should a writer join the queue (PENDING lock), existing reads (SHARED locks) will complete, grant an EXCLUSIVE lock to the writer process and then resume reading. This takes only a few milliseconds, meaning that the effective transaction throughput will hardly move from the 60/s rate quoted above.

I believe the default sqlite3 WAIT on an EXCLUSIVE lock is 3 seconds, so given the fact that 60 transactions per second is a reasonable expectation and that you seek to write to the database on average once every 10 seconds - I'd say sqlite3 is well up to the task and will only require the introduction of clustering once your traffic increases by a factor of 500.

Not bad and perfect for your requirement.

Comment: What happens if a lengthy select query (say 15 seconds duration) is underway, and an INSERT should occur at the tenth second? Would that insert fail?

Comment: In a default sqlite3 installation & setup (and with multi-threaded DB access) it would fail, yes, because your default timeout for waiting on the lock to be released is 5 seconds. However, you can deal with this extreme situation (15 second transactions) by 1) setting a longer timeout in your sqlite3 connection code and/or 2) catching SQLITE_BUSY timeout errors in your code and re-executing the transaction.

Comment: The OP hasn't mentioned reporting,  mentioning only concurrent insert queries, I'd have to agree with you, if we define his requirements narrowly, and exclude reporting. There may be 100 clients for the Apache server, but only one db client.  But with a large database, and one where some users are querying the database real-time, even as other small (single-row) inserts are hitting the database like raindrops hitting the sidewalk, the "extreme" situation is common. If that is his scenario, the OP should forget about zero-maintenance and zero-installation, and use a bona-fide back-end DBMS.

Comment: i see your point, and as you say, although read load is not mentioned, it could escalate quickly should the userbase increase or the project scope widen. In this case postgresql would be my recommendation. Still, I'd be curious to know the upper limits of sqlite3's operational capacity... will post what I find out here

Comment: OK, fruitful research time: two very useful docs from the sqlite website: http://www.sqlite.org/speed.html and http://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html. Findings: sqlite sacrifices complex features for speed and simplicity. In most cases sqlite3 is faster than enterprise class db engines. sqlite can drive a db of up to 140TB, allows multiple simultaneous reads and, like other databases stores data in files on disk. sqlite3 can be clustered into a db farm. Concurrency is NOT its strong point. The linked docs contain valuable info on which contexts are most suitable for sqlite and worth a read.

Answer (score 4):

Here is what SQLite has to say about appropriate uses of SQLite: http://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html In particular, that page says SQLite is good for low the medium traffic sites, exactly the sort of application that you're contemplating.

Seems like SQLite would work for you, unless you expect substantial growth. Depending on what you do in each request, I would expect that a query rate of 0.17 queries per second to be well within SQLite's capabilities.

For good user experience, you should design your site so that queries needed to service a single request take ~ 200 milliseconds. To achieve this, result sets should probably not touch more than a few score rows; and should rely on indeces, not full table scans. If you hit that, then you'll have enough headroom to serve 5 queries per second (at peak). That's 30x the requirement that you state in your question.

Answer (score 3):

The SQLite FAQ covers this topic: http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html (See: "(5) Can multiple applications or multiple instances of the same application access a single database file at the same time?")

But for your particular use, you'd probably want to do some stress testing to verify it'll meet your needs. 100 concurrent users might be a bit much for SQLite.

Answer (score 2):

I read through the FAQs, and it seems that SQLite has some pretty decent support for concurrency, but may require the use of transactions to be *sure* things are going to go well.

The comments above regarding Apache concurrency are correct: one Apache server can serve out multiple requests, the number depends on how many processes are run.  Most of the servers I run, its set to 3-5 processes, while on larger installations, it might reach 20.  The point here is that SQLite can more than handle a small to medium traffic web site, as it can do thousands of inserts a second.

I plan on using SQLite for my current project, but to be safe, I fully intend on using BEGIN TRANSACTION and COMMIT for any writing or concurrency-sensitive parts.

Bottom line, as usual, Read The Manual.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the discussion above about sqlite3, one more **awesome** feature introduced in sqlite v 3.7.0 is **WAL Mode**, in which you can read from multiple processes and can write with one process at the same time.

have a look at http://www.sqlite.org/wal.html