# Concurrent SQLite access in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, concurrency

Let me start saying that I did read most topics that pop up on search like those:
[SQLite and concurrency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14217249/sqlite-and-concurrency)

And yet I'm not convinced that solution proposing useage of a single `SQLiteDatabase` 
is a solution to a problem.

I followed implementation pattern as per https://github.com/dmytrodanylyk/dmytrodanylyk/blob/gh-pages/articles/Concurrent%20Database%20Access.md article.

I still do get errors. Here is my scenario:

I have main app running on UI. It does call database R/W functionality.
I also have AsyncTasks that I'm starting and they access DB as well on another thread.

Scenario:
Background task get's data from web and tries to store it in SQLite. Data size vary, can be up to 1000 inserts. To speed it up I wrap it into transaction. While bg thread writes into database I do some reads from database in main thread. And here is what I get:

> W/SQLiteConnectionPool﹕ The connection pool for database
>   '/data/data/com.hhh/databases/data.db' has been unable to grant a
>   connection to thread 1 (main) with flags 0x5 for 30.001001 seconds.

It's almost like locking happens. I don't understand HOW SQLite manages concurrency "internaly" but from what I see there is definitely issues with that.

Having singleton for DB object doesn't really help, even if it's serialized so what? Function will be waited for from 2 different threads but at the end both callers will get SQLiteDatabase and proceed into a "problem". I'm not convinced that code like this does a trick:

```
public synchronized SQLiteDatabase openDatabase(String purpose)
    {
        if (mOpenCounter.incrementAndGet() == 1)
        {
            // Opening new database
            mDatabase = mDatabaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        }

        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Database open counter: " + mOpenCounter.get() + " for " + purpose);
        return mDatabase;
    }
```

Going further - I *don't* see how keeping track of how many references given out and closing database on last reference helps. Why do I care if database get closed?

What I DO want is truly serial access to database. And question is.. How do I achieve that? Let's say I have 100 different functions running on different threads and they all can access database. How can I make sure that 2 don't run at the same time? I understand potential complications with performance but this is OK. All queries and DB access run pretty fast, even letting background thread do access to database first will not harm UI all that much.

I'm not very good with Java, but in C# I can use

```
lock(some object) { .... }
```

and put this structure into all my data access places. That would ensure that if I do DB stuff inside - other callers will be waiting.

Any suggestions? Comments? I want something maybe not *ideal* but simple. Ideal would be a code where I can distinguish if I want RO operations not serialized and write operations serialized. But from what I see even RO operations could cause problem when DB in a middle of transaction.

Comment: i'd say the issue is the transaction. it probably locks the db so no one can access it. I tend to use content providers for my db, never had any concurrency issue

Comment: Unfortunately content providers was not performing for us, we had to go away from it. Transaction is necessary, inserting 200 records goes from 60 to <1 seconds...

Comment: I can understand that. (there is a bulkInsert method, though). What I don't get in your question is this: does your write transaction locks the db for 30+ seconds?

Comment: No, it doesn't. It's less than a seconds, but other thread happens to call another write or read at the same time.

Comment: when you do your reads, do you call `getReadableDatabase`?

Comment: I did try both, seems to be no difference.

Comment: `Why do I care if database get closed?` the point is to avoid open/close of database, and to avoid closing a database being used by another thread. the `database` object should take care of the rest of the concurrency issues.

Comment: But if I open db once and just keep serving same object to all callers - it should be OK, right?

Comment: I tend to think so, but apparently there is something else.

Comment: Bit late for the party/ I faced same issue, can you show me the code where you are applying 'transaction'? That's where the real problem is.

Answer (score 0):

You can use synchronized blocks:

```
public void someMethod() {
    synchronized (someObject) {
        ...
    }
}
```